# "used as value" in function call

Tags: go

What's the proper way of calling functions when evaluating their values in conditional statements?

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
        if sumThis(1,2) > sumThis(3,4){
                fmt.Println("test")
        } else {
                fmt.Println("derp")
        }
}
func sumThis(a, b int){
        return a+b
}
```

this returns error:

```
./test4.go:4: sumThis(1, 2) used as value
./test4.go:4: sumThis(3, 4) used as value
./test4.go:11: too many arguments to return
```

How would you write this in Go?

Comment: The error message would be better as: "*void function call* used as value" or "... used as value, *but doesn't return a value*".

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You've forgotten to declare a return value. It should be:

```
func sumThis(a, b int) int {
// ...
```