# How to share variables through packages

Tags: variables, go, func

I'm trying to figure out how can I return a value from a function in a file of a `package name` to another `package`.
for example let's assume you have

```
package main

func main(){
   x := 5
   a := res.Test(x)
}
```

```
package res

func Test(x int) (y int){
    y := x*2
    return y
}
```

If I compile it I would get an error: `res.Test used as value`. Where am I doing wrong, how can I return `y` to the main/ and other package?
thx

Comment: "If I compile it I would get an error." What error are you getting, and how are you compiling it? Where are these files in relation to each other?

Comment: this looks like valid function usage - but main will fail to compile since the variable `a` is set but not referenced anywhere after being set.

Comment: @colminator how can i solve it

Comment: @Schwern I updated the post with the error

Comment: @wecandoit You should not have gotten that error with the posted code. I've added some speculation why in my answer, but double check you posted the real code.

Comment: Sure your package function returns something? [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561162/used-as-value-in-function-call)

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go (which describes how packages are used) and How to Write Go code (which describes how packages are written).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its most basic, a Go packages must be in their own file directory. `res` goes into `~/go/src/res/`.

```
// ~/go/src/res/res.go
package res

func Test(x int) (y int){
    // Note that y is already declared.
    y = x*2
    return y
}
```

Then your `main.go` can import this package.

```
package main

import(
    "res"
    "fmt"
);

func main(){
   x := 5
   a := res.Test(x)
   fmt.Println(a)
}
```

See also

- [Go Packages](https://golangbot.com/go-packages/)
- [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

---

Here's a little further debugging for your specific error.

Note that the `res` code you posted should not compile. You should get an error like `./res.go:4:7: no new variables on left side of :=`.

[`res.Test used as value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561162/used-as-value-in-function-call) indicates that `res.Test` does not return a value, but you tried to use it as one anyway. Your `res.Test` *does* have a return value.

Futhermore, your main.go is not importing `res`. You should have gotten an error like `undefined: res` but you didn't.

This indicates ***there's another `res` package floating around somewhere*** with a `Test` function with no return value.

Comment: I like your thinking but if there was another `res.Test` you would expect the error:
`res.Test used as value, but it returns nothing`

@wecandoit your comments and question are inconsistent. You need to post a small example with the exact code and error message.